# Trying to remove specific word from string in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm making an `ArrayList` that takes `String`s, and one method in the class takes a `String`, adds "urgent:" to the front of it, and puts it at the beginning of the list. I'm now writing a method that is supposed to take an `int`, a `String`'s position, and 'demote' that string to the end of the list.

However, if the string has "urgent:" in front of it, the method is also supposed to remove "urgent:" if it's demoted. Everything compiles and runs, but it's not removing "urgent:" and I'm not sure why.

```
public void addUrgetItem(String newItem) {
    String urgentItem = newItem; 
    items.add(0, "urgent: " + urgentItem); 
}

public void demote(int position) {
    int size = items.size();  
    String itemAtSpot = items.get(position); 
    items.remove(itemAtSpot); 
    items.add((size-1), itemAtSpot); 

    if (itemAtSpot.startsWith("urgent:")) {
        items.remove("urgent:"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say this:

```
items.remove("urgent:");
```

It's trying to remove the literal `String` "urgent" from the list itself, not from any specific item in the list. Instead, you need to remove that text from `itemAtSpot` before you add it back into the `List`. That would look something like this:

```
public void demote(int position) {
    int size = items.size();  
    String itemAtSpot = items.get(position); 
    items.remove(itemAtSpot); 
    if (itemAtSpot.startsWith("urgent: ")) {
        itemAtSpot = itemAtSpot.substring("urgent: ".length());
    }
    items.add(itemAtSpot); 
}
```

So after you remove the `String`, you take the substring of everything after "urgent:", and add that back onto the `List` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

By calling `items.remove("urgent:");` you're trying to remove a String that doesn't exist from the ArrayList, a String that contains `"urgent"` and nothing but urgent. Instead you must remove "urgent" from the **String** that is held by the ArrayList. This can be done by using String's `replace(...)` method, replacing "urgent:" with "": `myString.replace("urgent:", "");`

But having said this you actually could be doing things a whole lot better since you're doing a common programming evil: using Strings to hold logic information, more logic than they should. Instead of having the ArrayList hold Strings, why not have it hold objects of a custom class, a class that can have a `boolean urgent` field, fields that can easily be set via methods?

e.g.,

```
public class MyItem {
    private String text;
    private boolean urgent = false;

    public MyItem(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public MyItem(String text, boolean urgent) {
        this.text = text;
        this.urgent = urgent;
    }

    public boolean isUrgent() {
        return urgent;
    }

    public void setUrgent(boolean urgent) {
        this.urgent = urgent;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    // ... equals and hashCode methods based on text only
}
```

and....

```
private List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

// .....

public void addUrgetItem(String newItem) {
    MyItem item = new MyItem(newItem, true); 
    items.add(0, item); 
}

public void demote(int position) {
    int size = items.size();  
    MyItem itemAtSpot = items.get(position); 
    items.remove(itemAtSpot); 
    itemAtSpot.setUrgent(false);
    items.add((size-1), itemAtSpot); 
}
```